# What is the purpose of embeds_one in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I understand the concept of using `embeds_many` but what purpose does `embeds_one` serve especially when you only have one field in the embedded document as is shown in 1-N embedded document example on mongoid.org? Wouldn't it be better to create a field in the parent document?

Example on mongoid.org:

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :label
end


class Label
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  embedded_in :band
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In example they have given one field example only to show the definition structure. You can introduce more than one field in embedded documents.

embeds_one is used when there are multiple fields in embedded document which you don't want to store in the main document. When some fields are not mandatory for all documents to have we don't introduce in main document because it will make the document heavy. Instead of it we introduce embedded document which you can create based on requirement of main document.

Comment: For example, `embeds_one :address` with city, country, phone, etc.

Comment: So the only reason to use it is because it doesn't make the document heavy in terms of the amount of columns?  That seems like a very minimal benefit.  Are there other benefits for using this?

Comment: Usually embedding = read performance + scalability. Let's take for example SO. You can embedd question/answer comments within question, answer document. And it's means that you no need to join comments when you need to display answers/questions. If you no need to join -- you can move collection to separate computer to speedup your app. In relational database sub objects usually become a separate table (except denormalization). And in my practice there is very very many cases where i need to embedd documents.